# Python attribute error when uploading appointment to outlook calendar despite code functioning properly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, outlook, win32com

I am uploading an appointment from a pandas dataframe to an outlook calendar using the win32com.client module.

I have set the timezone to "US/Eastern" using:

```
df["Dates"] = df["Dates"].dt.tz_localize("US/Eastern")
```

because in a previous attempt the win32com upload said that I needed to include a timezone.

When I upload the appointment using

```
appointment = MyCalendar.Items.Add(1)
appointment.start = df["Dates"][0] + timedelta(hours = 2)
appointment.duration = 30
appointment.save()
```

I get the following 2 errors:

```
AttributeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones.get_dst_info()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

and it also prints:

```
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.localize_tso'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.pyx", line 218, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones.get_dst_info
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

however the code still uploads the appointment exactly as expected. I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it but I don't want to completely ignore it. I haven't found any posts with problems that address this exactly. Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: That's all that the script prints, how could I find the full traceback?

Comment: I see.  This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827582/message-exception-ignored-when-dealing-pandas-datetime-type

Comment: I found that one but the solution didn't work.

Comment: I got it to populate something else, now edited in the post.

Comment: It is strange. It might be a bug in pandas.  Possibly https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15986