# NoneType object has no attribute total_seconds [Python and Excel with win32com.client]

Tags: python, excel, windows, python-3.8, win32com

I am using win32com.client to read Excel spreadsheets into Python. However, some of my sheets have date and time cells, like the following:

[image]

`12/17/2021  5:00:00 AM`

When I read the sheets in with

```
import datetime
import pytz
import pandas
import time

def range_to_table(excelRange, tsy, tsx, height, width, add_cell_refs = True):
  ii = 0
  keys = []
  while ii < width:
    keys.append(str(excelRange[ii]))
    ii += 1
  colnumbers = {key:jj+tsx for jj, key in enumerate(keys)}
  keys.append('rownumber')
  mydict = {key:[] for key in keys}
  while ii < width*height:
    mydict[keys[ii%width]].append(excelRange[ii].value)
    ii += 1
  for yy in range(tsy + 1, tsy + 1 + height - 1): # add 1 to not include header
    mydict['rownumber'].append(yy)
  return (mydict, colnumbers)

ExcelApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks('myworkbook.xlsm')
sheet_num = [sheet.Name for sheet in wb.Sheets].index("mysheet") + 1
ws = wb.Worksheets(sheet_num)

height = int(ws.Cells(1, 3)) # obtain height from formula in excel spreadsheet
width = int(ws.Cells(1, 2)) # obtain width from formula in excel spreadsheet

myrange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(2 + height - 1, 1 + width - 1))
df, colnumbers = range_to_table(myrange, 1, 1, height, width)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
```

I get the following error printed several hundred times:

```
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timezones.pyx", line 220, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones.get_dst_info
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.localize_tso'
```

Is there any way to suppress the output of this error?

Comment: @BigBen, sorry, I have updated my code to include the whole program.

Comment: Perhaps see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827582/message-exception-ignored-when-dealing-pandas-datetime-type

Comment: Were you able to find solution to this. Facing same error.